# jComboBox getSelected Item error

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Hey guys im having some problems in displaying the selected item in jcombobox in the textbox here's my code:

```
double Cubao = 0;
double Zambales = 0;
final int Tickets = 50;
jLabel1.setText(String.valueOf(Tickets));
final double discount = .8;
String selecteditem = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();
String selectitem = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
int Passengers = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
if (jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().equals("Deluxe AC")) {
if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("Cubao_QuezonCity"))    
   Cubao = 780; 
}
if (jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().equals("Ordinary")) {
if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("Cubao_QuezonCity"))    
   Cubao = 500; }
jTextField4.setText(String.valueOf(Cubao * Passengers));

if (jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().equals("Deluxe AC")) 
if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("Iba_Zambales")) {
   Zambales = 530; 
if (jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().equals("Ordinary"))
if (jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().equals("Iba_Zambales"))
   Zambales = 300;
 {   

jTextField4.setText(String.valueOf(Zambales * Passengers));   
}
{


jTextField4.setEditable(false);
jTextField1.setEditable(false);
```

Now when i set the Bus Type to Deluxe AC it will show this:
http://tinypic.com/r/2s9zwcj/8 
But when i set the Bus Type to Ordinary nothing it will show:
http://tinypic.com/r/29mu0so/8

What seems to be the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checking the same fields multiple times which means you have a lot of netsted if blocks that make it hard to read the code. I suggest something like this:

```
if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("Cubao_QuezonCity")) {
    if (jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().equals("Deluxe AC")) {
        Cubao = 780;
    } else {
        Cubao = 500;
    }
    jTextField4.setText(String.valueOf(Cubao * Passengers));
    jTextField4.setEditable(false);
    jTextField1.setEditable(false);
}
if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("Iba_Zambales")) {
    if (jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().equals("Deluxe AC")) {
        Zambales = 530;
    } else {
        Zambales = 300;
    }
    jTextField4.setText(String.valueOf(Zambales * Passengers));
    jTextField4.setEditable(false);
    jTextField1.setEditable(false);
}
```